# ¿Existe una palabra para la acción de "adaptar para usar como arma"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

En Inglés existe la palabra "weaponizing" que significa:
"adaptar para usar como arma".

No se usa sólo para adaptar algo como un arma real (física), sino por ejemplo, se puede también decir "weaponizing the language" (usar el lenguaje como un arma).

Las traducciones que hacen al Español los traductores es simplemente "armamento", que no es el significado real de la palabra.

Existe una palabra así en Español?

¿Existe una palabra para la acción de "adaptar para usar como arma"?

Comment: Un simple teléfono móvil preparado y utilizado convenientemente como grabador de conversaciones y de videos, imágenes comprometedoras, e-mail, datos bancarios, hackeado..etc, puede utilizarse como un arma, según en las manos que caiga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre que la palabra **esgrimir** puede encajar como traducción de *weaponizing*, que tú mismo indicas que significa “adaptar para usar como arma”.

El Diccionario de la Academia contiene esta acepción:

> 2. tr. Usar una cosa o un medio como arma para lograr algún intento.

Y en el Diccionario de María Moliner, encontramos esta acepción:

> 2. Utilizar contra alguien cualquier cosa inmaterial.

Answer (score 3):

No le veo problema a usar el sufijo *-ificar*, que suele usarse para ese tipo de transformaciones extrañas. Por ejemplo (en el DRAE)

> *cosificar*: Convertir algo abstracto en una cosa concreta.
>
> *desertificar*: Transformar en desierto amplias extensiones de tierras fértiles.
>
> *caseificar*: Transformar en caseína.
>
> *osificarse*: Volverse, convertirse en hueso o adquirir la consistencia de tal.

Suena raro decir que "estás *armificando* tus palabras", pero solo porque el término no existe todavía. Sin embargo, está bien formado y puede usarse.

Comment: El periodismo escrito es una manantial de este tipo de términos, algunos con significado no directamente relacionado a la palabra origen, pero que aún así no dejan de ser interesantes. **Herramentizar** *(de herramienta)*: cuando alguien con poder usa las instituciones para fines o caprichos propios.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la expresión **armar** podría cumplir las condiciones. Veamos la primera acepción, tal como aparece en el *Diccionario de la lengua*:

> 1. tr. Proporcionar a alguien armas o algo que pueda ser usado como un arma.

Comment: Hmm me parece que no. Proporcionar a alguien armas no vendría a ser lo mismo que convertir a algo en un arma

Comment: Ahora que me fijo, es cierto; tienes razón.

Comment: He buscado otra solución, que creo que encaja mejor. La he redactado como respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Quizás no entendí correctamente, aunque desde mi punto de vista en Español pasa algo similar y utilizamos mucho la palabra "**armar**" en distintas situaciones. El lenguaje por si solo es un "arma" y las palabras su munición.

Así "armar la defensa" ó la contra replica, para referirnos por ejemplo a la forma ó estrategia que se va a seguir en la defensa ó ataque que realizan abogado y fiscal en un juicio con el sentido de preparar concienzudamente lo que se va a utilizar ante el juez, es "armar un juicio" para las partes. También es posible en un debate, en una sesión de control del gobierno, etc... armarse de una batería de preguntas, como conjunto de preguntas que serán utilizadas e irán destinadas hacia el adversario de forma adecuada.

Por otro lado, igualmente se puede emplear de forma más informal ó graciosa, cuando alguien dice " Me estoy armando de paciencia". Por ejemplo si tu pareja tarda mucho en el vestidor, o existe un gran atasco en el que te encuentras atrapado, se dice que una persona " se arma de paciencia", es decir toma todos los resortes posibles a su alcance para no perder los nervios, ya que en caso contrarío "explotaría", como un arma. Creo que esto puede ayudar a tu pregunta. Saludos

Incluso podrías ir armado de libros ó de recetas de cocina hacia una acción que vas a realizar.

Comment: Me parece que cuando dicen "armar la defensa" se refieren a "ensamblar la defensa" , o "unir o encajar las piezas que componen algo" que es otro de los significados de armar, y que no tiene que ver con arma en el sentido de "Instrumento, medio o máquina destinados a atacar o a defenderse."

Comment: H. Pablo, El V. mismo armar como V. transitivo, tiene varias acepciones,1. Proveer de armas a un ejército, país.2. Disponer de un arma. Sin embargo como bien dices también existen otras, imagino que te refieres a esas3 montar, componer, articular, planear, organizar4. escandalizar, alborotar, pelear, reñir, disputar. Sin embargo el verbo es el mismo, "armar" y "arma la defensa" es utilizar todos esos resortes, investigaciones, planificación, etc, y emplearlos como arma. Imagina un barco de guerra, armándose con distintos tipos de armas que utilizaran así convengan ya sea para atacar o defender

Answer (score 1):

–*¿Existe una palabra para la acción de "adaptar para usar como arma"?*–

No como tal, pero si existe la palabra **municionar** o **amunicionar** que si bien no se utiliza como metáfora, *municionar el lenguaje* bien podría ser interpretado como cargarlo de munición para disparar con él.

> Municionar: proveer y abastecer de municiones